# calculate the OB using prospective method

Tags: actuarial-science

I'm learning about the prospective for loan repayment but I'm having trouble creating the equation. Here was my problem ([loan repayment- finding the loan if end payment increases by certain amount](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4079926/loan-repayment-finding-the-loan-if-end-payment-increases-by-certain-amount))

I'm finding the outstanding balance after the fourth payment using the prospective method.

I learned that both prospective and retrospective methods give the same answer but with different equations.

If I used retrospective I should get $3301.20(1.1)^4 - 500(1.1)^3 -510(1.1)^2 -520(1.1) -530 = 2448.68$

the prospective method is done by calculating the outstanding balance by looking to future payments.
I tried doing a similar method when getting the loan where $10-4=6$ payments left on the loan

$$\require{enclose}
\begin{align}
540  a_{\enclose{actuarial}{6} 0.1} + 10(Ia)_{\enclose{actuarial}{10} 0.1} = 540\left(\frac{1-\left(\frac{1}{1.1}\right)^6}{0.1}\right)+10\left(\frac{\frac{1-\left(\frac{1}{1.1}\right)^{10}}{\frac{0.1}{1.1}}-10\left(\frac{1}{1.1}\right)^{10}}{0.1}\right)
\end{align}$$

but I'm getting a $2642.90$.

Comment: The increasing annuity has the same number of payments as the level annuity.

Comment: I'm not getting the same number as the retrospective. I don't know if something else is supposed to be added to the equation.

Comment: Your increasing annuity has too many payments.  Read my previous comment again.

Comment: wait wait: the 540 is wrong should be 530. and the exponents for the increasing should be 6 since you said increasing annuity has the same number of payments as the level annuity

Comment: I'm sayin that 
\begin{align}
540  a_{\enclose{actuarial}{6} 0.1} + 10(Ia)_{\enclose{actuarial}{10} 0.1}
\end{align}
should be
\begin{align}
540  a_{\enclose{actuarial}{6} 0.1} + 10(Ia)_{\enclose{actuarial}{\color{red}{6}} 0.1}
\end{align}